# pug rendering templates of view subfolders in Node.js (express)

Tags: javascript

When all the templates are in the views folder then we successfully render them. I make the structure of folders and views then the internal templates are not visible for rendering.

This is the structure of my folders and, the `contacts.pug`template is not visible for`render()`

[image]

**app.js**

```
    const createError = require('http-errors');
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const logger = require('morgan');

    const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
    const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

    const app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, '/views'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public/templates'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public/fragments')]);
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        next(createError(404));
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function (err, req, res) {
        // set locals, only providing error in development
        res.locals.message = err.message;
        res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

        // render the error page
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('index', {});
    });

    router.get('/about', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('about_us.pug');
    });

    router.get('/portfolio', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('portfolio');
    });

    router.get('/contacts', (req, res,next) => {
      res.render('/public/templates/contacts',{});
    });

     router.get('/products', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('products.pug');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

**contacts.pug**

```
    extends views/layout

                    block content
                        h1 contacts
```

**layout.pug**

```
     html
        head
            title= title
           link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        body
            include public/fragments/header
            block content
```

**header.pug**

```
    block header

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='./stylesheets/public/fragments/header.css')

    div
        ul
            li: a(href='/') Home
            li: a(href='/about') About
            li: a(href='/portfolio') Portfolio
            li: a(href='/contacts') Contact
            li: a(href='/products') Products
```

**error**

> Error: Failed to lookup view "/public/templates/contacts" in views directories "C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\views", "C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\views\public", "C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\views\public\templates" or "C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\views\public\fragments"
>       at Function.render (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>       at C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\routes\index.js:18:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\Xiaomi\IdeaProjects\online_shop_server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

Comment: i solved teh problem added `app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');` to app.js

Comment: If it's solved, post the solution below as an answer and accept it, in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved my problem this way:**

-**added in `app.js` `app.locals.basedir = path.join (__ dirname, 'views');`, added default paths to the desired subfolders in the views folder.**

```
    const createError = require('http-errors');
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const logger = require('morgan');

    const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
    const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

    const app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, '/views'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public/templates'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public/fragments'),
        path.join(__dirname, '/views/public/templates/layout')]);
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        next(createError(404));
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function (err, req, res) {
        // set locals, only providing error in development
        res.locals.message = err.message;
        res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

        // render the error page
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

-**in the link handler `index.js` added the correct paths to the templates after updating the folder structure and pug files in the views folder.**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('index', {});
    });

    router.get('/about', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('about_us',{});
    });

    router.get('/portfolio', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('portfolio',{});
    });

    router.get('/contacts', (req, res,next) => {
      res.render('contacts',{});
    });

    router.get('/products', (req, res, next) => {
      res.render('products',{});
    });



    module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Old question but someone else may have similar problem, here is my solution.

I suggest you create `public` directory in the same level as `views` folder( not inside it).
Then use

```js
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./views');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
```